# Where exactly in Italy to where in Russia is the train going?

Tags: realism, film-location, stalingrad-1993

In the film [Stalingrad (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108211/), where exactly are they passing while on the the train in one scene here? It is supposed to be in Italy, going to Russia.

Where exactly in Italy to where exactly in Russia are they going?

I think it is said it is [Porto Cervo, Italy](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/07021+Porto+Cervo,+Province+of+Olbia-Tempio,+Italy/@41.1616669,8.9491884,8.71z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x12d940ba7d106431:0xc70a48fba03230f1!8m2!3d41.1315336!4d9.535745) but how can it be? That is in Sardinia, so they need to take a ferry to Italy and from there go to Russia.

Whereabouts in Russia are they going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The town mentioned and also shown in the first scene (beach), and the one they started the ride on the train from, is actually Cervo near Imperia located in the northwest of Italy.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Cervo+IM,+Italia/@43.9268759,8.1093533,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x12d940ba7d106431:0xc70a48fba03230f1!2s07021+Porto+Cervo+OT,+Italia!3b1!8m2!3d41.1315336!4d9.535745!3m4!1s0x12d2684a23a634ed:0x14baaca14bb66187!8m2!3d43.9250373!4d8.1141758) is Cervo near Imperia

Answer (score 1):

The train travels directly to a stylised version of Stalingrad on the Eurasian side of the Wolga river. The city was renamed to Wolgograd in 1961 as part of the “de-Stalinization” program

Here’s the modern day city’s location, shown on Maps:

[Modern day Stalingrad](https://goo.gl/maps/qywz8RP5KmFxHKJAA)